# loading resources dynamically for iphone 3GS and 4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

Since the display resolution is different, I wonder if there is an official guide or tutorial that shows how to load images. icons, nibs, etc. dynamically for iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official guide is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html). (You'll need a developer account)

Most of the time, you'll just need to make a high resolution image with a "@2x" suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone Application Programming Guide has a section on [Supporting High-Resolution Screens](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html) that should answer your questions.