# Problem with a Retina Display Image

Tags: iphone, image, uinavigationcontroller, background, retina-display

I have a TabBarController app where the first tabBarItem is a NavigationController...
I assign programmatically an image background to the navController with this code:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OverviewBg.png"]];
```

The "OverviewBg.png" image is the exact size of the view between tabBar and NavBar.
If I try my app in the iPhone 4 simulator, the high definition image isn't loaded correctly and is showed the normal image...

How can I solve this mistake? The best way to use colorWithPatternImage method is use an image with the exact size of the view or a pattern image?

Thanks

Comment: Hello. What is the name of your image in HD ? (copy paste the exact name please ^^)

Comment: I asked kind of the same thing some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548794/loading-resources-dynamically-for-iphone-3gs-and-4 basically you need a file OverviewBg@2x.png for retina display

Comment: I know this... My retina display image is named OverviewBg@2x.png but it isn't loaded properly... Is it possible that there is a bug in the colorWithPatternImage method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using initWithPatternImage method of UIColor class.
I created and allocated an UIColor instance, I assigned to it an image and then I used it with background.

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OverviewBg.png"]];
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = background;
```

Hope this can help other :)